# dead/deadly serious - sure

Tags: adverbs

I think that these are correct:

> I am dead serious.
>
> I am deadly serious.
>
> I am dead sure.

But this is wrong

> I am deadly sure.

If my assumption is correct, what's the reason for this phenomenon?

Answer (score 5):

*Dead* used in this way is informal, and is an intensifier. It does not mean the same as *deadly*.

It happens that, because of the meaning of *serious*, *dead serious* and *deadly serious* overlap; but they are not the same. *Dead serious* means that whatever it is is very serious. *Deadly serious* suggests that whatever it is has dire implications (not necessarily literally "deadly", but something pretty nasty) - but this is because of the collocation of "deadly" and "serious",

No such matching of meanings would occur in *deadly sure*, so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: But meetings can be *deadly boring* without being dire. As in "deadly serious", it is a common collocation. The same is true for  "deadly pale" a person who is white as a sheet, or extremely ill. (I was going to post an answer but you beat me to it.) For me it's just a common collocations there's no reason why "They are deadly wrong" should not make sense but no one says it likewise "deadly = extremely sure"

Comment: I partly agree. Those are common collocations; but in each of them _deadly_ has a meaning metaphorically related to death. This is unlike intensifier _dead_ which is bleached of semantic meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Agreed that it's uncommon rather than being wrong, though I would say "deathly pale" rather than "deadly". I've used other intensifiers for boring meetings, but I'll not mention those here...